# Problem on bounded variation functions

Tags: measure-theory

I need to give an example of a $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ continuous function compactly supported but not of bounded variation.

I was thinking of $x\sin(1/x)$ kind of function. But exactly that does not work, need modification

Comment: If you want it continuous on $[0,1]$, the family you want to look at is $x^a \sin(x^b)$,$a>0,b<0$. Then consider the partition whose nodes satisfy $x^b=\pi/2+n \pi$.

Comment: @Ian: I need $a<=b$ also

Comment: @Malkhor You ultimately do need $a \leq -b$, but that comes out of the calculation. The point is that the family $\{ x^a \sin(x^b) : a>0,b<0 \}$ has a function of the sort you want. Though actually, with your edit, it doesn't quite serve your purposes as is. Instead you'll want $x^a \sin(x^b) \chi_{[0,\pi^{1/b}]}$.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414: how is it coninuous ? it does not have limit on zero.

Comment: @Ian: understood. thanks.